# Looking for canvas events library truly cross platform

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm developing a HTML5 application and I'm looking for some JS library handling input on canvas elements, suitable for both desktop and mobile platforms (otherwise, what's the point of html 5?)

Basically I need to drag shapes around, since it's a drawing-like application, and dragging is also used to navigate in the canvas (this is so it's more mobile friendly - they don't have scrollbars). It would be nice if it supported pinch to zoom, too

I know kinetic.js and similar, but they seems to have separate libraries for mobile and desktop

Comment: Take a look at [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js)

Comment: What a fantastic piece of software!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas doesn't have elements, nor does a circle that you draw, for example, on a canvas have any events attached to it - it's quite different from working in the DOM.

You need to keep track of the x/y positions of each of the 'elements' that you draw on your canvas, and when a mouse, or touch, event occurs, take the x/y position of that event and match it against the x/y position of your canvas 'elements'.

However, what you'll need to do also, it a bit of basic collision detection, so that the x/y positions of your input (mouse/touch) don't have to match up exactly with the x/y position of your canvas 'elements'.

Using Kinetic, though, you could fairly easily detect when you're on a mobile device that has touch event support, and then alter the 'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click', etc. events within Kinetic:

```
var _START, _MOVE, _END;
if('ontouchstart' in window) {
    _START = 'touchstart';
    _MOVE = 'touchmove';
    _END = 'touchend';
}
else {
    _START = 'mousedown';
    _MOVE = 'mousemove';
    _END = 'mouseup';        
}
```

...and then use _START/_MOVE/_END in Kinetic's addEventListener function.

Hope that helps somewhat. Of course, do be careful setting global variables, it's generally bad practice, and this is only an example.

Kinetic is [here](http://www.kineticjs.com/), and there's a good write up of touch and gesture events (gestures for pinch/zoom) [here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/07/touching-and-gesturing-on-iphone-android-and-more/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Like you said yourself, it's a bit of a hack, so let's wait and see if anyone knows a better way :)

Comment: No probs. Just found [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mobile-events/) example of using touch events in Kinetic.js that may be of some help. 
In my rush to answer, I didn't realise that there's no need to hack apart the Kinetic source (stupid, really). You can use the touch-device detection above and just pass _START/_MOVE/_END into Kinetic's addEventListener function. I'll make changes in my original answer, too.